# Force immediate evaluation in powershell script (copy variable by value, not reference)

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I'm having a problem with the following code

```
foreach ($ex in ("foo", "bar", "baz")) {
$timer = New-Object Timers.timer
$taction =  {
    Write-Host "Timer fired for: $ex"
}
$timer.Interval = 1000 
$timer.AutoReset = $false
$timer.Start()

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed -SourceIdentifier "$ex" -Action $taction
```

}

This code gives the following output

```
Timer fired for: baz
Timer fired for: baz
Timer fired for: baz
```

But I would want to have it foo, bar and baz. The problem seems to be that the $ex variable is read in the end by all Timers so whatever value it has, they all get it. How do I copy the value of $ex in the $taction so that it is unique?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `[scriptblock]::Create()`, this evaluate arguments at the creation:

```
foreach ($ex in ("foo", "bar", "baz"))
{

$timer = New-Object Timers.timer
$taction =  [scriptblock]::create("Write-Host Timer fired for: $ex")

$timer.Interval = 1000 
$timer.AutoReset = $false
$timer.Start()

Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName elapsed -SourceIdentifier $ex  -Action $taction
}
```